# How is running an .exe from cmd different than double clicking it?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a .exe file on Windows (Electron app) That hangs when I launch it via double click but runs fine if I launch it from the cmd prompt or a .bat file. What all can be different?

Again this is an Electron based app from a project I am currently working on.

Comment: Why don't you attach a debugger to File Explorer, and see where it hangs? It's likely some crappy shell extension that gets in the way (and doesn't, when launched from the command prompt).

Comment: first thing that come to my mind is the working folder.

Comment: Yes, I ruled out the working folder by walking into the root C drive from cmd and launching but it still works in that case.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know how to debug file explorer and I'm not sure how it will help.

Comment: Does the app launch but hang, or does it never launch? If the app launches but hangs, then connect a debugger to your hung app to see why it is stuck.

Comment: Can you print something on the very first line? That will tell you if you are getting into the app or something is getting in the way before you have control.

Comment: Our app starts with a login window. after logging in it hangs. I need to figure out how to get logs when launched from a double click. The logs naturally go to the console when run from the command line. Does anyone know how to grab logs from an Electron-based .exe?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something in the registry I can look for which is impacting how the file explorer shell launches apps. But I don't know where to begin looking! It's been about a decade since I've done any serious Windows registry hacks.

Comment: This is only a guess. Does Electron use a console window? You might need to create a console window if one does not exist. I would say that is the only difference that is not application-dependent.

Comment: Yes, but this project is rather complex. It logs things using various approaches spawns multiple processes and not everything goes to the standard JS console. It'll take the better part of my day just to figure out where to log what and how. I'm actually looking into this route now.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out (with the help of a rather clever co-worker) what the difference is. In my Electron app we have some console.log calls happening in a forked process. When run from the .exe these calls are attempting to write to stdout which is unavailable. Adding a redirect in the code to re-route the output to the file system fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Specifically, I did:
my_program.exe > /c/mytemp/stdout_dump

Answer (score 0):

I got `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` from double clicking a program I made, but it runs ok from cmd. If i right click and run as administrator it works also.

I have no idea what makes a program require administration right, sometime it does, sometime it doesn't. From my experience it depends on the code or the compiler, but I cant give more details than that.